# The length of a string

Tags: c

Why is that when I entered;

```
char string[10^4];
scanf("%s", string);
```

I got a runtime error and this;

```
char string[10000];
scanf("%s", string);
```

worked fine?

Btw, both worked fine when the input was not a large string. For example, when the string was `"abc"`, it worked fine in both cases but  when it was `"wqrjljowspxmsvkjkkogvcyheydhikggaypnjdkbvhnpcxyojowhquouuuceeimgicurheuenjtritfshbbyxpsrlwxpfjwpnsjxwdbjnxaxqhryisyhkqavnxnuillwdutzywkntkkmtckbuikga"`, it worked for only the second case.

Forgive my extremely long string. it is part of my test case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value of `10^4` is 14 because the `^` is the XOR operator.

You can't simply write 1E4 which is 10<sup>4</sup> because that's a floating point constant and array bounds must be integer constants.  You could cast it (`char string[(int)1E4];`), but why not just write clearly and concisely what you mean: `char string[10000];` as you did in the second example.

There's an argument that you should write:

```
if (scanf("%9999s", string) != 1)
    …handle input error or EOF…
```

This protects you from a buffer overflow.

Comment: Interesting..it is possible to type cast it, right? like: `(int)1E4`

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the type cast, but why not just write `10000`?  (It _is_ shorter.)

Comment: @Manuel: That would be a cast from `float` to `int`. You'll probably get the exact value you expect, though the standard does not guarantee it.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, you can write `char t[(size_t) 1E4];`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler writing `10000` is easier. I was just curious

Comment: @Deduplicator: 6.3.1.4 "When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool,
the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero)." 5.2.4.2.2 guarantees than 10-digit decimal floating point numbers can be roundtripped through a double; 6-digit through a float. 5.2.4.2.1 guarantees that any positive integer less than 32768 can be represented as an int. I think that all of that is sufficient to guarantee that (int)1E4 is 10000.

Comment: @rici: Thanks, I thought the guarantees for floating-point-numbers were much weaker.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The guarantees are pretty weak. However, the theoretical model outlined in 5.2.4.2.2 requires floats to consist of a integer significand and an integer exponent of some unspecified integer base. The range of exponents is required to include [-1e37,+1e37], so 0 is always an available exponent and thus all integers less than 10^{FLT,DBL}_DECIMAL_DIG are representable, where those values must be at least 6 and 10. Hence languages like `awk` and `lua` can internally use `doubles` for integers and still guarantee accuracy of 32-bit integer computations. (In practice, 53 bits.)

Answer (score 4):

```
char string[10^4];
```

The above is an array of length 14, because `^` is bitwise-exclusive-or, not power.
All else is the same as for the second case, though with much lower ceiling.

```
char string[10000];
scanf("%s", string);
```

The above has 3 points-of-failure:

1. 10000 bytes might be too much (just about always on the stack, which is often severely limited. Consider heap-allocation with `malloc()`, or static buffers).
2. The input might contain a token more that 9999 bytes long (+1 for terminator).
3. You do not check for input-failure, but will probably blithely assume success.

Comment: @chux: De jure it might not be on the stack, though it will be with near-certainty. Still, changed.

Comment: In embedded apps with no hosted system, `main()` variables are commonly in the same space as globals.

Comment: Most non-embedded systems usually won't have a problem with 10 KiB of characters on the stack, but it is a good idea to remember that there are limits on the amount of space on the stack (so a deeply recursive function with a 10 KiB stack usage would be a bad idea, for example).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: If you go kernel-side on x86, 8K minus some management-structures is all you get on Linux. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/kernel-stacks

Comment: Writing kernel code is very different from general C code.  We're really violently in agreement, I think — you need to be aware of your programming environment and its limits.

Comment: @chux `main` may be called recursively, so there must be more to it.